# Как сделать сортировку в Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Всем доброго времени! 
Либо аномалия, либо я не то делаю, есть сортировка которая работает на англ. версии сайта(используется плагин WPML)
но на укр. версии не работает, использую такой метод сортировки

```
if (ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == "uk") {
        if (  get_key_access() ) {
        $query = new WP_Query(array(                
            'post_type' => 'episodes',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'orderby' => 'none',
            'order' => 'ASC',
            'meta_query' => array(
                array(
                    'key' => '_crb_association|||0|value',
                    'value' => 'post:programmes:' . $post->ID,
                ),
            ),
        )); 
    }

    if (  is_user_logged_in() )  {
        $query = new WP_Query(array(                
            'post_type' => 'episodes',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'orderby' => 'none',
            'order' => 'ASC',
            'meta_query' => array(
                array(
                    'key' => '_crb_association|||0|value',
                    'value' => 'post:programmes:' . $post->ID,
                ),
            ),
        )); 
    }

    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() )  {
    if ( ! get_key_access() ) {
        $query = new WP_Query(array(                
            'post_type' => 'episodes',
            'posts_per_page' => 1,
            'orderby' => 'title',
            'order' => 'ASC',
            'meta_query' => array(
                array(
                    'key' => '_crb_association|||0|value',
                    'value' => 'post:programmes:' . $post->ID,
                ),
            ),
        )); 
    }
}
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Поборол таким способом

```
if (  is_user_logged_in() )  {
        $query = new WP_Query(array(                
            'post_type' => 'episodes',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'orderby' => 'menu_order',
            'order' => 'ASC',
            'meta_query' => array(
                array(
                    'key' => '_crb_association|||0|value',
                    'value' => 'post:programmes:' . $post->ID,
                ),
            ),
        )); 
    }
```

и в самой странице Page Order, почему не могу сказать, воспринимает только отрицательное значение, таким способом если поставить -999, то ролик становится первым и т.д. для остальных